# O Que é um Override de javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

Estou trabalhando em um projeto onde tenho que fazer o `'parser'` de um site remoto pra alterar vários conteúdos dele, tudo está direitinho, exceto as funções que envolve `javascript/ajax.`
As funções não funcionam, o site `'parseado'` me retorna sempre um erro

> "desculpe estamos com problemas'',

mas este erro ocorre por conta do `javascript.`
Eu estava usando um `proxy em PHP` pra fazer o `'parser'`, mas por ser lento, eu quis fazer meu próprio, e nada mais é que um "alterador de links":

```
function parserSite($link){

    $opts = array(
    'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"
    )
    );
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    $html = file_get_contents($link , false, $context);
    $results = preg_replace('/href="(https:\/\/)?([^"]+)"/', "href=\"https://sitetal.com\\2\"", $html);
    $results = preg_replace('/src="(https:\/\/)?([^"]+)"/', "src=\"https://sitetal.com\\2\"", $results);

reuturn $results
}
$link = $_GET["link"];
$site = parserSite($link);

echo $site;
```

O site funciona tudo direitinho, exceto os `javascript's`.
No proxy que eu utilizava, o mesmo erro ocorria quando desativava a opção **"Override native Javascript",** quando esta opção estava habilitada, tudo funcionava normalmente.
Mas o que é isto de "**Override native Javascript"?**
é possível eu fazer pra meu `script?`
Postei em `PHP e Javascript` porque não sei ao certo qual das duas linguagem terei que usar pra tal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está tendo essa diferença entre o site acessado via navegador e o download via PHP pois o website em questão provavelmente utiliza javascript para renderizar suas partes, o que você pode fazer é utilizar um *headless browser* para simular um navegador acessando o site.

Uma sugestão é usar o [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/), talvez com [esta](https://github.com/jonnnnyw/php-phantomjs) biblioteca para usa-lo através do php

Comment: Muito obrigado!
Fiz meu headless browser e deu certinho ;)